# Protecting efficiently a critical section which is mostly read-from and rarely written-into

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, critical-section

I have a multi-threaded application.

It includes a couple of global variables that most of the time are read by several different threads, and very rarely are written by others.

I can protect them with a mutex, but that would be rather "expensive" under these circumstances.

Most of the time, Readers will "lock each other out", the scheduler will intervene if priority inversion is required, etc, etc... All of that without any real need, as reading alone shouldn't do any harm.

So I'm looking for some other type of OS resource that will help me to achieve the goal of protecting these global variables at a lower cost.

The first thing that comes to mind are Counting Semaphores, but I'm not sure how to use them properly in this case, or if they even support what I have in mind... And here is what I have in mind:

1. A single shared object, called Sem, which supports the following atomic operations:

   - Inc: if count >=  0, increment count; otherwise, lock the calling thread
   - Dec: if count >   0, decrement count and signal all pending threads if count == 0
   - Get: if count ==  0, set count = -1; otherwise, lock the calling thread
   - Put: if count == -1, set count =  0 and signal all pending threads
2. Reader:

   - Sem Inc
   - Read variables
   - Sem Dec
3. Writer:

   - Sem Get
   - Write variables
   - Sem Put

Of course, the atomic operations are not "for free", as they require disabling the interrupts. Nevertheless, it seems much more efficient than using a mutex, with all the unnecessary additional context-switching which will most likely come along with it.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is my solution for this problem correct?

   - If yes, what type of OS resource should I use for 'Sem'?
   - If no, where are the pitfalls?
2. Is this a known problem with a standard solution?

The application is running over ThreadX kernel, but any OS-agnostic answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I missed it in your post, but are you familiar with reader/writer locks? They sound like what you're looking for.

Comment: You're looking for a reader-writer lock, a mutex that allows many readers to enter a critical section, or a single writer at a time. The [Windows API supports this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx), im not sure about other OSs.

Comment: A very lightweight approach may be to use a spinlock as used in the Linux kernel. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spinlocks.txt

Answer (score 3):

You can implement shared lock & exclusive(reader/writer) lock using System V Semaphores, 
sem_op in struct sembuf with value 0 will wait for zero, so here is a simple example:

If you have N item, create N*2 semaphore, each item with two semaphore, representing shared lock & exclusive lock:

To shared lock a item:
1. semop(0) on its exclusive lock.
2. semop(1) on its shared lock.

To shared unlock a item:
1. semop(-1) on its shared lock.

To exclusive lock a item:
1. semop(0) on shared lock.
2. semop(0) on exclusive lock.
3. semop(1) on exclusive lock.

To exclusive unlock a item:
1. semop(-1) on exclusive lock.

And a set of operation performed in semtimedop() is atomic.

Answer (score 1):

If your updates are really infrequent and your read access so numerous that a mutex would cause contention, you can use a minimalistic transactional approach.

This assumes you don't need a lightning fast reactivity (which is the case in 99.9% of the applications bothering to implement shared accesses when a simple client-server data flow would be more than sufficient and way more efficient).

#### Basic idea

Each reader maintains a local copy of the reference data.

When a writer wants to perform an update, it increments the version number after modifying the reference data.

The readers have only to check the reference version number before accessing their local copy.
If the numbers match, they can proceed freely.
If the numbers don't match, they have to acquire a new copy.

#### Naive implementation

Here is a naive implementation. You could make it more efficient by replacing the mutex with a reader/writer lock, condition variables or whatever smarter mechanism, but since the point is to favour reads of non-modified data, the optimization is likely unnecessary.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>   
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

// ================================
// minimalistic transaction wrapper
// ================================
template <class T>
class shared_read; // forward declaration

// --------------------------------
// transaction writer
// --------------------------------
template <class T>
class shared_write {
    friend class shared_read<T>;
    atomic<int> version;
    mutex             lock;
    T&                data;

public:
    shared_write(T& obj) : data(obj), version(0) {}

    void update (T& new_version)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> waiter(lock);
        data = new_version;
        version++;
    }
};

// --------------------------------
// transaction reader
// --------------------------------
template <class T>
class shared_read {
    int        version;
    shared_write<T>& reference;
    T                payload;

public:
    // take an initial copy on construction
    shared_read(shared_write<T>& ref) : reference(ref), payload(ref.data), version(ref.version) {}

    // get an up to date copy
    const T& get(void)
    {
        // update to latest version
        while (version != reference.version)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> waiter(reference.lock);
            payload = reference.data;
            version = reference.version;
        }

        // return local copy
        return payload;
    }
};
```

#### Usage

To use this, create a global write wrapper for your target global object and have each thread create a read wrapper from the write wrapper:

```
// at toplevel
Something global;
shared_write<Something> writer;

// inside each reader thread
void reader_worker (void)
{
    shared_read<Something> reader(writer);

    ...

    const Something& my_something_copy = reader.get();
}

// inside each writer thread
void writer_worker (void)
{
    Something my_new_version_of_something;
    my_new_version_of_something.initialize (whatever);
    writer.update (my_new_version_of_something);
}
```

#### Caveat

When a new version is produced, all readers will queue to retrieve the new copy, which will have a sizeable cost.

This approach favours successful reads heavily (a successful read has neglectible overhead while an update is costly) and is slightly less responsive (a reader can work with an outdated copy for a bit longer than when using a serialized access).

#### Testing

Here is a quick and dirty test harness :

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>

#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// --------------------------------
// measurement
// --------------------------------
int num_refresh;

// ================================
// minimalistic transaction wrapper
// ================================
template <class T>
class shared_read;

// --------------------------------
// transaction writer
// --------------------------------
template <class T>
class shared_write {
    friend class shared_read<T>;
    atomic<int> version;
    mutex             lock;
    T&                data;

public:
    shared_write(T& obj) : data(obj), version(0) {}

    void update (T& new_version)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> waiter(lock);
        data = new_version;
        version++;
    }
};

// --------------------------------
// transaction reader
// --------------------------------
template <class T>
class shared_read {
    int        version;
    shared_write<T>& reference;
    T                payload;

public:
    // take an initial copy on construction
    shared_read(shared_write<T>& ref) : reference(ref), payload(ref.data), version(ref.version) {}

    // get an up to date copy
    const T& get(void)
    {
        // update to latest version
        while (version != reference.version)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> waiter(reference.lock);
            payload = reference.data;
            version = reference.version;
            num_refresh++;
        }

        // return local copy
        return payload;
    }

    // debug: get object version
    int get_version(void) { return version; }
};

// ================================
// test
// ================================

// --------------------------------
// parameters
// --------------------------------
double write_frequency;
const int num_threads = 4;
const int num_accesses = 5000000/num_threads;

int mismatches;
atomic<int> global_ref_1 = 0;
atomic<int> global_ref_2 = 0;

// --------------------------------
// some global object
// --------------------------------
struct dummy {
    int ref;
    dummy(int ref = 0) : ref(ref) {}
};

dummy global;

// --------------------------------
// transactional version
// --------------------------------

// writer wraps the global
shared_write<dummy> writer(global);

void worker1(void)
{
    // local reader
    shared_read<dummy> reader(writer);

    for (int i = 0; i != num_accesses; i++)
    {
        if ((rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) < write_frequency)
        {
            writer.update(dummy(++global_ref_1));
        }
        else
        {
            const dummy& val = reader.get();
            if (val.ref != reader.get_version()) mismatches++;
        }
    }
}

// --------------------------------
// basic mutex version
// --------------------------------

mutex write_sync;
void worker2(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != num_accesses; i++)
    {
        if ((rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) < write_frequency)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> waiter(write_sync);
            global.ref = ++global_ref_2;
        }
        else
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> waiter(write_sync);
            if (global.ref != global_ref_2) mismatches++;
        }
    }
}

// --------------------------------
// test harness
// --------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    vector<thread> threads(num_threads);

    for (write_frequency = .9; write_frequency > .0005; write_frequency /= 2)
    {
        time_t start;

        // test transactional version
        num_refresh = 0;
        mismatches = 0;
        start = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i != num_threads; i++) threads[i] = thread(worker1);
        for (thread& t : threads) t.join();
        int duration1 = (int)((clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000);
        if (mismatches != 0) printf("mismatches 1 : %d\n", mismatches);

        // test mutex version
        mismatches = 0;
        start = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i != num_threads; i++) threads[i] = thread(worker2);
        for (thread& t : threads) t.join();
        int duration2 = (int)((clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000);
        if (mismatches != 0) printf("mismatches 2 : %d\n", mismatches);

        double refresh_per_access = (double)num_refresh/num_accesses/num_threads;
        printf("frequency %.3f refreshes %.3f (%2.1f) duration %d / %d ms\n", write_frequency, refresh_per_access, refresh_per_access/write_frequency, duration1, duration2);
    }
}
```

Compiled with Visual Studio 2013 in debug mode (to purposedly slow things down), it produces the following output on my 4 cores CPU:

With 4 threads and 5.000.000 accesses:

```
C:\Dev\PHP\_StackOverflow\C++\TransactionalGlobal\Debug>TransactionalGlobal.exe
mismatches 1 : 754
frequency 0.900 refreshes 0.092 (0.1) duration 12956 / 7747 ms
mismatches 1 : 21947
frequency 0.450 refreshes 0.297 (0.7) duration 8878 / 7786 ms
mismatches 1 : 64116
frequency 0.225 refreshes 0.324 (1.4) duration 2535 / 7682 ms
mismatches 1 : 56733
frequency 0.113 refreshes 0.240 (2.1) duration 1606 / 8119 ms
mismatches 1 : 39681
frequency 0.056 refreshes 0.156 (2.8) duration 1109 / 5157 ms
mismatches 1 : 20363
frequency 0.028 refreshes 0.090 (3.2) duration 853 / 6982 ms
mismatches 1 : 7923
frequency 0.014 refreshes 0.049 (3.5) duration 685 / 6849 ms
mismatches 1 : 4982
frequency 0.007 refreshes 0.026 (3.7) duration 580 / 8658 ms
mismatches 1 : 1180
frequency 0.004 refreshes 0.013 (3.8) duration 543 / 6492 ms
mismatches 1 : 1378
frequency 0.002 refreshes 0.007 (3.9) duration 534 / 7491 ms
mismatches 1 : 1058
mismatches 2 : 1920
frequency 0.001 refreshes 0.003 (3.9) duration 519 / 7684 ms
```

You can see the basic cost of the thread processing is about 520 ms. The extra cost of synchronization rises with the percentage of updates/reads, go on par with a naive mutex approach around 50%, and becomes worse afterward.

"mismatches" are a coarse measurement of when a thread works with outdated data (i.e. someone else has updated the data since this thread acquired a local copy).

with 8 threads and 350.000 accesses (about 15 times less!):

```
C:\Dev\PHP\_StackOverflow\C++\TransactionalGlobal\Debug>TransactionalGlobal.exe
mismatches 1 : 6
frequency 0.900 refreshes 0.091 (0.1) duration 8435 / 9440 ms
mismatches 1 : 55
frequency 0.450 refreshes 0.252 (0.6) duration 7443 / 9286 ms
mismatches 1 : 224
frequency 0.225 refreshes 0.183 (0.8) duration 4270 / 7691 ms
mismatches 1 : 1032
frequency 0.113 refreshes 0.140 (1.2) duration 2061 / 7522 ms
mismatches 1 : 1202
frequency 0.056 refreshes 0.104 (1.8) duration 670 / 10036 ms
mismatches 1 : 572
frequency 0.028 refreshes 0.046 (1.6) duration 480 / 7242 ms
mismatches 1 : 834
frequency 0.014 refreshes 0.038 (2.7) duration 130 / 3521 ms
mismatches 1 : 247
frequency 0.007 refreshes 0.025 (3.6) duration 40 / 10303 ms
frequency 0.004 refreshes 0.013 (3.8) duration 40 / 10375 ms
frequency 0.002 refreshes 0.007 (4.1) duration 40 / 10234 ms
mismatches 2 : 2421
frequency 0.001 refreshes 0.003 (4.0) duration 40 / 8372 ms
```

Unsurprisingly, having more threads than available cores produces a dramatic performance drop due to mutexes contention on each core. On the other hand, the cases of working with outdated data is also reduced:).

The non-modified read case is not affected by mutex contention, so the base execution time drops from about 520 to 40, (a factor of 13), roughly the 15x reduction in total number of transactions.

Under 1% modifications/reads, the cost of updates remains neglectible.

Answer (score 0):

First I would have tried to figure out if your platform has an instruction for locked reads/writes, many contemporary ones do. As for any synchronization primitives available on threadx - each of those will disable interrupts, re-schedule, etc., so if your HW lacks support for the above, and you feel threadx mutex is that (how much?) "expensive", just disable the interrupts. Well, this is harmless if you read your global into a local variable once in a thread cycle, but in this case I would have used a mutex. In threadx, it's really cheap.

Linux read/write locks will disable preemption (interrupts), too.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are aware that you can use the ThreadX mutex. It is quite fast and deterministic. 
Have you done any performance measurements?
Are you site it will not meet your needs?

Comment: First of all, thank you. Quoting from the question: "I can protect them with a mutex, but that would be rather "expensive" under these circumstances. Most of the time, Readers will "lock each other out", the scheduler will intervene if priority inversion is required, etc, etc... All of that without any real need, as reading alone shouldn't do any harm."